# Some cck fields not turning into HTML

Tags: 6, entities

This happens in my custom Zen-based theme where I made a custom node type 'events'. I put print_r($node) inside of my node-events.tpl.php which gave all the ckk fields including the ones that didn't turn into HTML i.e. not displayed.

When viewing this type of node in a stock drupal theme, this problem doesn't occur so everything gets displayed as desired.
This means my viewing permissions are in check and also under *admin->content type-> 'events' -> display fields* hidden is turned off (set to standard just the way it was when I didn't have the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't think I'm understanding the symptom.

If something shows up in one theme and not the other I would check if you have anything wierd in your template.php or if you have overridden any of the content-field.tpl.php files

Comment: I actually took the content-field.tpl.php out of the templates folder that's in my custom theme folder and that solved it. Now I'm struggling with what it is about that file that makes it disappear. I've overridden that content-field file to paste some php in it that i found on the internet. I'm only getting started with the php templating side of this. But I guess it's another question alltogether. Thanks!

Comment: It's actually possible to override just one field (the event organizer field), or fields of a certain type (text fields) with something called [template naming suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656#field-suggestion)